# Django Group By relation's data

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by

In Django,

I can do value(), and then distinct() to group by.

```
A
{
     Foreign Key B
}
B
{
     String name
}
```

However, is it possible to group using a related object's data? I.e. In the above relation,  can I group A by B's name?

Comment: have you tried doing A.objects.all().value("B__name").distinct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can order_by on the FKey model.

```
A.objects.order_by('B__name')
```

Iff you can't, You need to use the Django ORM's Annotation API, to make a new field and you will be able to order it accordingly:

```
A.objects.annotate(bname='B__name').order_by('bname')
```

Comment: The 1st one works. The 2nd one doesn't becaus annotate requires an aggregation inside it.

Thanks